# What is the meaning and grammatical construction of 人って?

Tags: grammar, particles, colloquial-language, quotes, particle-って

I am trying to understand the grammar behind "[noun]って".

I looked up some examples on space alc web, and 人って seems to mean people, someone, or some person. 
I have seen other examples of the [noun]って usage, so I guess its common but probably I am missing something.

Comment: Most likely the quotation particle って, which can behave a lot like the topic marker in many cases. The specific context would be useful to answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

って is a colloquial particle and has two main functions.

1. Being used as a colloquial topic marker (instead of は or とは), e.g.

   > 人ってすごいよね。
   >   People are awesome.
2. Being used as a quotation marker (instead of と or という), e.g.

   > 変な人って言ってたよ。
   >   She said you are a little weird.
   >
   > 人って言葉は何か変だな。
   >   The word "hito" is kinda weird.

Comment: I had read somewhere that this grew out of といって, and that this literal "talking about" sense is how this construction came to be used in place of the は topic marker, and the と quotation marker.

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi That's what I had thought until someone pointed me to [a dictionary](http://dic.search.yahoo.co.jp/search?p=%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6&stype=prefix&aq=-1&oq=&ei=UTF-8). The dictionaries usually say って comes from とて.