# Function of a って at the end of a sentence?

Tags: particle-って

> と、菅沼教諭が士道の手から握力計を取ると、それを様々な角度から、矯めつ眇めつした。
>
> そして、はあと息を吐く。
>
> 「あー……多分、バネ部分の金属疲労だな。昔から使ってたやつだからガタが来てたんだろう。大丈夫だったか五河」
>
> 「え？　はあ……」
>
> 士道が答えると、ごくりと息を吞んでいた生徒たちの雰囲気が一気に緩んだ。
>
> 「あーあ、なんだよ、驚かせやがって」
>
> 「まあ、そりゃそうだよな、針振り切るならともかくバネ引き千切る**って**」
>
> 得心がいったように、生徒たちがうなずく。

What would be the function of the bold って?

Answer (score 2):

This って is working as a colloquial and emphatic topic marker (=(の)は, とは, というのは).

- [What is the meaning and grammatical construction of 人って?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/12327/5010)

  > Being used as a colloquial topic marker (instead of は or とは)
- [Confused about って in this sentence](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/50246/5010)

And とは/って can express a surprise, a *tsukkomi*, or a similar sentiment:

- [Help with お逃げになられるとは](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/24976/5010)

  > The important thing is that one can end a sentence with this 「とは」 without directly stating how one feels about an event/situation.
- [The usage of とは in 緊急招集とは、おだやかではないな](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25323/5010)

So バネ引き千切るって is a colloquial version of バネを引き千切るのは or バネを引きちぎるとは, which literally means "(but) tearing off the spring was (impossible / surprising / etc)".

Answer (score 1):

I thought I might add a note on intonation.

って at the end of a sentence is spoken with a rising intonation if you are actually asking or asking for something, such as a definition of a word or phrase, or an explanation for a situation. When spoken with a falling intonation, it usually indicates surprise, incredulity, or bewilderment on the part of the speaker.

Answer (score 0):

I see a common pattern here, a lot of people wonder "What is useage of X at the end of the sentence?" It's often some form of omission. The sentence hasn't ended. The rest is just chopped off, so the usual grammar apply. You just have to supplement the missing bits.

「まあ、そりゃそうだよな、【 圧力計の 】針【 を 】振り切る【　くらい　】なら【 まあそのくらい力の強い人間もいるだろうと理解できるけれども 】バネ　【　を　】引き千切るって【 いうのは想像を絶するような握力であり、そんな怪力を持った人間が身近にいればそれは想像を絶する事！だけど、士道が説明してくれたことによって、バネが切れたのは金属疲労によるためと分かったから、まあそういうことなら話は分かる 】」