# Does って in this sentence work as a topic marker or have some other meaning?

Tags: particle-って

For clarity: A guy starts speaking in a rude manner to an upperclassman (unknowingly). so the upperclassman's reply is:

> いきなりタメ口**って**
> 一応　同中の先輩なんだけど

Translation:

> Well, that's not very polite!
> I'm actually your senpai.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This って is a colloquial topic marker that is used in place of [とは](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25323/5010). とは/って used like this expresses the speaker's (negative) surprise, bafflement, etc. The senpai used って because he did not expect タメ口.

Related: [Function of a って at the end of a sentence?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/86559/5010)